# Integration via Foursquare API

Tags: api, foursquare

Is it possible to delete venues via the Foursquare API?
I don't see any mention of it at https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot delete venues via the API. If there is a problem with a venue you should use the `venues/flag` endpoint to push the venue into a moderation queue.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/flag